# Grep ip address with regex from a text file inside the same directory

Tags: string, search, grep, find, ip

I need a linux command to grep for a specific IP address inside text files inside the same directory as I am. I would normally use

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' file.txt
```

But I have different text files with different names. So I want to grab just the first possible IP address of all text files inside the same directory as I am rather than using the name of the text file (which is different each time). How would this possible? Maybe with a `find` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep -m 1 -h -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' *
```

I assume no filename starts with a `.`.

See: `man grep`